# gnuplot: Plotting X,Y coordinates and their label

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following file (test.dat):

```
A   149 127
B   19  157
C   49  127
D   149 147
E   9   127
F   49  12
G   129 127
```

I would like gnuplot to plot these points with their label (a dot a position (149, 127), another dot at (19, 157), etc.). How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should help

gnuplot> plot "data.txt" using ($2+3):($3+3):1 with labels, "data.txt" using 2:3