# labels on a 2D plot, is it possible in gnuplot 4.0

Tags: label, gnuplot

I've seen several examples of labels in gnuplot (where two columns define the 2D plot, and a third column is used to make labels that apply to the points in the 2D plot) but I can't seem to get them to work on my gnuplot.

We have 4.0, and it seems like the standard examples are for 4.2 and higher.

Is there any way to use three columns to define a 2d plot with labels in gnuplot 4.0?

I've tried things like:

```
plot "datafile.gnu" using ($3+3):($4+3):2 with labels, "datafile.gnu" using 3:4 with lines
plot "datafile.gnu" using 3:4:2 with labels, "datafile.gnu" using 3:4
plot "datafile.gnu" using 3:4 with lines, '' using 2 with labels
....
```

3 & 4 are columns for the x & y and 2 is the column containing the label I want at each point.

No matter what I try I'm getting errors back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764077/gnuplot-plotting-x-y-coordinates-and-their-label   This is not documented that I can see in the 4.0 manual (latest I have), so I'd presume you need to update (or use set label point by point)

Comment: yeah, I saw that example and tried it... and it didn't work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnuplot4.0 is ancient.  As such, I don't have access to a copy of it -- However, you might try something like this:

```
!awk '{printf "set label \"%s\" at %f,%f point\n",$3,$1,$2 }' datafile.gnu > labels.gnuplot
load "labels.gnuplot"
```

Comment: I think I'll just upgrade in my account.  I don't have root access but I should be able to download into my account and run it there.

Comment: @DanS -- Yeah, that shouldn't be too much of a problem.  Good luck.